# Can't upload files to Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have the following script which tries to upload backup files from my instance `vm` to the bucket.

When  executing the script, it only uploads the files of smaller size up to 30 GB in size, however it does not load the files that are >= 80 GB to the bucket.

```
python 2>/dev/null - <<EOF
import os
import socket
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client()
today = datetime.today()
current_hour = today.strftime('%Y/%m/%d/%H')
hostname = socket.gethostname()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("fsa_backup")
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('/hanabackup/log/DB_FRD/'):
  for file in files:
      backupfilename = os.path.join(subdir, file)
      if 'log_backup' in backupfilename:
          only_filename = backupfilename.split('/')[-1]
          backup_file = hostname + '/log/' + only_filename
          blob = bucket.blob(backup_file)
      blob.upload_from_filename(filename=backupfilename)
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('/hanabackup/data/DB_FRD/'):
  for file in files:
      backupfilename = os.path.join(subdir, file)
      if 'COMPLETE_DATA_BACKUP' in backupfilename:
            only_filename = backupfilename.split('/')[-1]
            backup_file = hostname + '/data/' + only_filename
            blob = bucket.blob(backup_file)
      try:
            blob.upload_from_filename(filename=backupfilename)
      except Exception as e: 
            logging.fatal(e, exc_info=True)            
EOF
```

[files backup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9kDo.png)
[bucket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGdEp.png)

Comment: I'm not sure what is the problem here.

Comment: What error messages are there? It's not clear whether you have a programmer error or whether this is a Google Cloud support issue (like if they have file size limits).

Comment: Hello .
The script works well for me and loads all the smaller files and the large ones does not come up. On the other hand, it does not generate any .log file when executing the script.
Up to 5tb of objects can be stored in the cloud storage information.

Answer (score 2):

With large files there is a higher risk of network interruptions or other obstacles when uploading a file. For such cases [it is recommended](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload) to use resumable media upload available as a parameter in `MediaFileUpload` method. It will upload your file in chunks. In this GitHub [code snippet](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-file-transfer-json-python/blob/master/chunked_transfer.py#L123) you can see how it can be done.

Comment: Thank you so much for the "code snippet" link! I was trying to get this working for a couple days and that did it for me